# Find questions with exact tags?

Tags: support, search

Really short question, but I couldn't find an answer:

Is it possible to find questions, which have some single tag, or some specific set of tags, *and no other tags*?

If yes, **how?**

I tried the `-[tag]` syntax to exclude some tags from results, and it is good enough for most practical purposes, so I guess this question is mostly just curiosity.

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question does not evan have word "tag", let alone cover searching for exact tag set. But removing the "btw" part about *Advanced Search Tips* to remove any overlap...

Comment: Not remotely the same question. This duplicate flag needs to be removed.

Comment: Ok, now seems to link to a real duplicate with answer, thanks @random